# How to access DAO enumeration constants in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, dao, enumeration

In PowerShell, how do you access DAO enumeration constants, such as RecordsetTypeEnum dbOpenTable (1) or DataTypeEnum adVarNumeric (139)? Right now, I'm simply putting them in as magic numbers, but it would be much cleaner and easier to read to refer to the proper constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RecordsetTypeEnum dbOpenTable (which comes from Access), you can use:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao") | Out-null
[int][Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.RecordsetTypeEnum]::dbOpenTable
```

For DataTypeEnum adVarNumeric (which comes from ADODB, not Access) you can use:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("ADODB") | Out-null
[int][ADODB.DataTypeEnum]::adVarNumeric
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom `enum` type with the names needed:

```
enum DAODataType {
    adBigInt             = 0x14
    adBinary             = 0x80
    adBoolean            = 0x0B
    adBSTR               = 0x08
    adChapter            = 0x88
    adChar               = 0x81
    adCurrency           = 0x06
    adDate               = 0x07
    adDBDate             = 0x85
    adDBTime             = 0x86
    adDBTimeStamp        = 0x87
    adDecimal            = 0x0E
    adDouble             = 0x05
    adEmpty              = 0x00
    adError              = 0x0A
    adFileTime           = 0x40
    adGUID               = 0x48
    adIDispatch          = 0x09
    adInteger            = 0x03
    adIUnknown           = 0x0D
    adLongVarBinary      = 0xCD
    adLongVarChar        = 0xC9
    adLongVarWChar       = 0xCB
    adNumeric            = 0x83
    adPropVariant        = 0x8A
    adSingle             = 0x04
    adSmallInt           = 0x02
    adTinyInt            = 0x10
    adUnsignedBigInt     = 0x15
    adUnsignedInt        = 0x13
    adUnsignedSmallInt   = 0x12
    adUnsignedTinyInt    = 0x11
    adUserDefined        = 0x84
    adVarBinary          = 0xCC
    adVarChar            = 0xC8
    adVariant            = 0x0C
    adVarNumeric         = 0x8B
    adVarWChar           = 0xCA
    adWChar              = 0x82
}
```

Then pass `[DAODataType]::adVarNumeric` instead of `139`

Comment: I was hoping more for referencing the original DAO enum, rather than building my own. Something like [DAO.RecordsetTypeEnum]::dbOpenTable (but that doesn't work for some reason).

Comment: @whairst For that, you'll need to import [the appropriate interop assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2022)